# Can the referee in a football match request a video review?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, video-review

In pro soccer, can the referee request VAR to analyse an incident even though there is no warning from VAR to the referee?

Answer (score 0):

At least in the Dutch national league, it's possible for the referee to request a VAR review. [Here](https://www.knvb.nl/themas/sportiviteit-en-respect/video-assistant-referee-var/veelgestelde-vragen-var) is a link to the FAQ on the website of the national organisation (in Dutch):

> #### Wanneer wordt besloten of de VAR in actie komt?
>
> De communicatie kan zowel door de scheidsrechter als de VAR worden gestart. Dit is dus als de scheidsrechter vermoedt dat hij een ernstig incident mist of als de VAR van mening is dat de scheidsrechter een incident heeft gemist of duidelijk fout heeft beoordeeld.

My translation:

> #### When is decided if the VAR needs to act?
>
> The communication can be started by both the referee and the VAR. So this is if the referee suspects he misses a serious incident or if the VAR thinks the referee missed an incident or made a clear error judging it.

Answer (score -1):

The [rules of the IFAB](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/video-assistant-referee-var-protocol/#principles) include the following rule about the VAR:

> 12. As the VAR will automatically ‘check’ every situation/decision, there is no need for coaches or players to request a ‘review’.

This does not mention the referee, but it is still implied the VAR will look at everything that happens during a game. So no request from the referee would be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

> In pro soccer, can the referee request VAR to analyse an incident even though there is no warning from VAR to the referee?

**It's a clear *YES*.** The [IFAB Video Assistant Referee Protocol](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/video-assistant-referee-var-protocol/#principles) states that:

4. Only the referee can **initiate** a ‘review’; the VAR (and other match officials) can only **recommend** a ‘review’ to the referee.

Comment: Can downvoter explain how this answer with official backup can be wrong/improved ?!